# field theory finite extension problem

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let m be co-prime to $[K(α) : K]$, where $α$ is algebraic over K. Show that $K(α)$ = $K(α^m)$

Attempt: One inclusion is easy as $α^m$ belongs to K(α) for second inclusion I think I need to use tower of extension but from that I can only deduce that $X^m$-$α^m$ is reducible how to proceed after that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not true. Let $K= \mathbb Q$, $\alpha = e^{2 \pi i/3}$, and $m=3$.

In answer to the questions asked in the comments:

- For an assumption on $K$: The result is true if $K$ is assumed to contain a primitive $m^\text{th}$ root of unity: In this case it is a standard exercise to show that a radical polynomial of the form $x^m-a$ factors into equal degree irreducible polynomials, which implies that the degree of $K(\alpha)$ over $K(\alpha^m)$ divides $m$.
- I suspect, though I'm not sure how to prove, that the result should hold for arbitrary $K$ if both $m$ and $\Phi(m)$ are assumed to be relatively prime to $[K(\alpha):K]$. In other words, both $p$ and $p-1$ are relatively prime to $[K(\alpha):K]$ for every prime $p \mid m$. This covers both when $\operatorname{irr}_K(\alpha)$ is $x^n-a$ and when it's a cyclotomic polynomial.

Comment: This example is so natural, one might conjecture OP meant $m - 1$ coprime to $[K(\alpha) : K]$.

Comment: @Bib-lost I'm pretty sure $m$ coprime to $[K(\alpha):K]$ should be a necessary condition to cover the case when $\alpha$ is a root of a an irreducible radical of the form $x^n-a$.

Comment: are there any restriction on field K to make result possible?

Comment: What about $m$ coprime to $[K(\alpha) : K]!$?

Comment: @Ninjahatori see my edit

Comment: @Bib-lost see my edit